# Selenium WebDriver Best Practice for Explicit Wait in the POM

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Using the page object model where can I place my declaration of WebDriverWait so that it can be resused in POM? The below code is in the page class and the webelements are displayed in each page's own object repository. Here is my sample code

```
public bool IsAt()
{

    try
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        wait.Until(Driver => ObjectRepository.EnterButton.Displayed);

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }


  return  ObjectRepository.EnterButton.Displayed;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to re-use the `WebDriverWait` object, you can either place it in the POM-level class or wrap the Driver into a DriverWrapper class that maintains its own instance of the `WebDriverWait`, exposing the `WebDriverWait` when necessary but allowing it to be instantiated at the same time as the `WebDriver` - especially considering the `WebDriverWait` has a direct dependency on the `WebDriver` object itself.

Comment: Thanks @Frank would you be so kind as to share an coded example so that I may better understand what your saying?